# Image is not displaying inside Lighbox React Native

Tags: react-native, lightbox, navigator

I'm trying to navigate between two scenes using Navigator in react-native. Below is codea for scenes "Example", "LightboxView1".
 I have put an image inside Lightbox in second scene "LightboxView1". When I run the code, Image doesnt display.

Also If I try to put the image in first scene's lightbox, I get this error "react.children.only expected to receive a single react element child"

```
var Example = React.createClass({

  navigate(id) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id: id,
        component: LightboxView1
    })
  },


  render: function() {

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.text}><Text>Test Text 1</Text></View>
        <Lightbox navigator={this.props.navigator}
          renderHeader={close => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={close}>
              <Text style={styles.closeButton}>Close</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}>
          <View style={styles.customHeaderBox}><Text>I have a custom header</Text></View>
        </Lightbox>
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.navigate('second') } style={ styles.button }>
         <Text>Second View</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  },
});

var LightboxView1 = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.text}>
          <Text>Lighbox view 1: some example text</Text>
        </View>
        <Lightbox underlayColor="white" navigator={this.props.navigator}>
          <Image style={styles.contain} resizeMode="contain"
            source={{uri: 'http://www.yayomg.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/yayomg-pig-wearing-party-hat.jpg'}}
          />
         </Lightbox>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.props.navigator.pop()}>
            <Text>First View</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  },
});

var LightBoxProject = React.createClass({

  _renderScene: function(route, navigator){
  if(route.component) {
    var Component = route.component;
    return (<Component navigator={navigator} route={route} {...route.passProps} />);
  }
   switch(route.id){
    case "first":
      return(<Exmaple navigator={navigator} />);
    case "second":
      return (<LightboxView1 navigator={navigator}/>);
  }
},

  render: function() {

    return (
      <Navigator
        ref="navigator"
        style={styles.navigator}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        initialRoute={{ id: 'first', component: Example}}
      />
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you didn't set the `height` and `width` of your image in `styles.contain`. The `Image` won't render until it's told its size.

As for the `react.children.only` error, wrap both the `Image` and the header in a single `View` and put it and it alone directly inside the `Lightbox`.

**edit:** since iOS 9 you by default cannot load resources via HTTP. To override this you need to add [App Transport Security Exception](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) to your `Info.plist`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: contain: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 150,
       },

I did with this style, still not working

Comment: You should specify both `width` and `height` of the `Image`.

Comment: For the second error react.children.only I wrapped them in a <view> but Image is not displaying.

Comment: I got the fix for image not displaying. I used another images's uri and its working fine. I don't know the issue with some particular uri's. Anyways appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Ah! Is the new uri `https://` by any chance? Since iOS 9 you need to add [App Transport Security Exception](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) to your `Info.plist` file to load resources via http.